# Extract text from string in php with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with a regex in php to extract function arguments from a string. I am parsing a javascript file in php and want to extract 2 function arguments from a line. Here is an example of how the lines may look:

```
"Backbone.Radio( 'comments ').trigger("added:comment " ,function(){});"
```

From this line I want to extract the word **comments** and **added:comment** without any whitespaces or quotes.

I have tried with:

```
$arrMatches = array();
$strRegEx = "/\\(\\s*['\"]\\s*([^)]+?)\\s*['\"]\\s*/";
$nMatches = preg_match_all($strRegEx, $strLine, $arrMatches);
```

But this will give me something like: **( 'comments '** and **("added:comment "**

I would appreciate some help with how to solve this.

Comment: is it not possible to 'clean' them after extraction. So just remove `(` and `'` and `"` after you've gotten your results? Or will this method affect it, as the comments itself may contain brackets?

Comment: I could clean them after extraction but i would prefer to have the regex only extract the parts i need so i do not need that extra step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
<?php

$regex = '~\(\h*([\'"])(.+?)\h*(?!\\\\)(?=\1)~';
$string = "Backbone.Radio( 'comments ').trigger(\"added:comment \" ,function(){});";

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => comments
    [1] => added:comment
)
*/
?>
```

The regex looks for single/double quotes, captures them and looks for the next single/double quote which is not escaped. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xB7eB4/1).

---

<sup>**Warning:** While this might work in this particular example, it is usually the last way to use a regex - have you considered using a parser instead?</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This works great. But what is the benefits of using if i use a parser and what parser could i use for this example?

Comment: @sudden01: Well, it totally depends on your Input strings. If they are all of the mentioned format, this will very likely work. Problems will only occur if you face nested brackets, e.g. `Backbone.Radio('comment_function("testparam")')` which is totally JS valid.

Comment: Ok, then i think regex will do fine. The lines i am checking will always have this format. Thanks again for your help i will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, something like this would work:

```
$re = "/(?<=\\()(?:[ '\"]*)([\\w\\d\\:]+)(?=[ ]*['\"]*)/"; 
$str = "\"Backbone.Radio( 'comments ').trigger(\"added:comment \" ,function(){});\""; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

you can add other items to the matching group as required.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this also works. Since i am no regex expert i do not know which solution is the best but they both work for my case.